# Different property variable for Local and prod Environment (Spring)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am working on an Spring web application in where I need to have variable's that will have different value in local environment and other value in production environment.

For Eg (file upload directory). My file upload directory is different for local and prod environment.

Currently I am doing it by checking the host name (if 'localhost' then A else B) and taking this approach. By there is another way to solve this problem via property files, Does anybody provide me pointers to how to approach that?

Comment: You should use spring profiles and load properties files based on the currently active profile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can load properties based on the current spring profile or profiles. To set a spring profile I mostly set a system property named `spring.profiles.active` to the desired value e.g. `development` or `production`.

The concept is pretty simple. Read the currently active profile from the system property. Build the filename and load the properties file using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Using the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` will make it easier the access those properties through `@Value` annotations. Note that this examples assumes one profile is active. It may need some extra care when multiple profiles are active.

*Java based configuration*

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", "production");
        String propertiesFilename = "app-" + activeProfile + ".properties";

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(propertiesFilename));

        return configurer;
    }
}
```

You could also import multiple configuration classes annotated with `@Profile`. Spring would select which configuration to use based on the currently active profiles. Every class could add it's own version of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to the application context.

```
@Configuration
@Import({Development.class, Production.class})
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {}

@Configuration
@Profile("development")
public class Development {}

@Configuration
@Profile // The default
public class Production {}
```

---

As Emerson Farrugia stated in his comment the `@Profile` per class approach is a bit drastic for selecting a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Annotating a `@Bean` declaration would be much simpler.

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile("development")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer developmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        // instantiate and return configurer...
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile // The default
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        // instantiate and return configurer...
    }
}
```

Comment: That second example could lead to a mixture of concerns if the intent is for a single `Development` configuration to contain all (unrelated) beans to be registered in the development environment. It's better practice to annotate the `@Bean` methods with `@Profile` in that scenario IMO, i.e. in a `PropertySourceConfiguration` `@Configuration` class.

Comment: @Brat thank you for the answer, But I am unclear for this part "I mostly set a system property named spring.profiles.active to the desired value e.g. development or production" where do you actually set this?

Comment: You can set a system property in your code (using `System.setProperty`), JVM options, JAVA_OPTS etc. For test cases you can annotate your tests with `@ActiveProfile`

Comment: @Bart, I have applied the same logic as you suggested. I have created two files app-dev.properties and app-openshift.properties, and I have kept them in resources folder. It is working fine in my local environment but not able to pick the property file on server where I have deployed my war. Where should I keep the file?

Comment: @abhishekgaloda Read the source of org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile

Comment: I was using version 3.1 it doesn't work at method level, though I agree that it seems to be working with newer versions

Answer (score 8):

One solution that does not involve Spring Profiles at all is to use something like the following:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:config.properties,file:/path/config/config.properties"
                              ignore-unresolvable="false" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

What this does is tell Spring to look for properties using two files, the file in your jar/war, and one that can be anywhere in the file system. The ignore-resource-not-found means that if one of the files is not found, Spring won't complain.

Using this setup the second file can be controlled by DevOps people and can contain anything of their choosing, thus overriding any properties in your classpath properties file file.

**UPDATE:**

You could do the same with Java Config using the following bean in your configuration class

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    Resource[] resources = new Resource[ ] {
            new ClassPathResource( "config.properties" ),
            new FileSystemResource("/path/config/config.properties")
    };

    pspc.setLocations( resources );
    pspc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
    return pspc;
}
```

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen You could annotate the configuration class with [@ImportResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) if you want to load addition XML resources

Comment: @geoand Your example loads mutliple files. but how does it distinguish between environments as OP asked?

Comment: @Bart As I mentioned in the beginning of my answer, the second path is a file system path whose contents can be specific to the environment where the application is deployed. In test /path/config/config.properties could have creditCard.bank.isProduction = false , while in production it would be creditCard.bank.isProduction = true. This kind of setup helps DevOps people control the environment of your application more effectively.

Answer (score 6):

I've been banging my head half a day on this, and the solution I've ended up with is a combination of the other answers here.

Bart's solution had for me the drawback of using a dynamic prop file, so that my IDE "forgot" everything about it and couldn't suggest me which properties were used and where. Geoand solution had for me the drawback that the config file "should be in place somewhere". I can see why this is convenient in certain scenarios, but I tend to prefer one single artifact deployable in any environment, so I don't have to "park" files in strategic places for the app to pick up.

The solution for me therefore is:

```
- config.properties (default properties, usually local development env)
- config.staging.properties (overrides depending on the env)
- config.prod.properties (overrides depending on the env)

<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true"
                              location="config.properties,
                                        config-${profile}.properties"/>
```

The magic is the `ignore-resource-not-found="true"` that allows me to fire my local development env without setting any special `profile` variable. The missing file will just be ignored.

Instead, I set that variable in my various deployment environment, e.g. `-Dprofile=staging`, and then the file will be found and the overrides applied.

Answer (score 1):

In my case above any solutions didn't work so I did some google from my end and finally found some working solution for it.

I've modified the above class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return configurer;
}
}
```

Instead of defining dynamic file name inside the method. I am defining the file name as below which does the magic for me.

> @PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")

at the top of the class. By following Bart's solution I was not getting any errors but I was getting all the properties to value null defined inside property files.

by using my approach spring is able to recognize properties defined in VM arguments and in environment variable both.
Note: I am using a non-spring boot project.

Answer (score 0):

you can add -Dspring.profile.active=local in your spring boot application, when you start your server. It will pick application-local.properties