# How to get parameter from Tomcat in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

My project works in several tomcat servers. Project Structure is same, when I updated and deployed. I don't want to change database, and baseUrl settings manually.

I'm using Spring MVC. I want to write settings/configurations into server and get from server.

Comment: Did you even try to seach for anything? Have a look at [JNDI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment variables in different servers (pre-prod, prod etc) to accomplish something like this.

There are multiple ways to use environment ways in properties for spring framework.

Here is a good post [Different property variable for Local and prod Environment (Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757318/different-property-variable-for-local-and-prod-environment-spring)

Answer (score -1):

You can append the server settings in your tomcat server and the base URL in your project properties file.

Comment: i need to know how to?