# Specify env dependent properties file at maven build

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm an ok Java developer, but I've inherited a huge J2EE/JSP/Springs/Maven project, and I'm a total novice w. Maven & Spring, etc.

All I want to do is specify different env dependent .resource files at build-time w. something like

`mvn install -Dprofile=development`

And I want regular Java classes to load that environment specific properties file at runtime. I don't mind if Maven copies "application.development.properties" to "application.properties", or there is some configuration variable available in the java file like

```
String env=${profile};
```

or

`String env = System.getProperty("profile");`

or whatever. I know there are LOTS of Stackoverflow responses to almost this - but I've spent hours now on google, coming real close with snippets - but nothing that put it all together for me.

I did figure out ONE thing that works, but it's inelegant & takes an extra prop file read. But in case someone else needs this & no-one has a better answer:

You can include the properties-maven-plugin, & "generate-resources", which will create a properties file with the properties defined in POM.xml. But you can override properties defined in the pom from the command line - so include the plugin in your pom:

`<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputFile>
                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/envdef.properties
              </outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>`

and the default envtype property:

    `<properties>
        <envtype>local</envtype>
    </properties>`

You can build with, say "mvn -Denvtype=production install" & it will create an "envdef.properties" file with the single property "envtype" - production, local, whatever the build parameters. Read that property file, get the envtype in your Java code, then read the custom environment dependent properties file based on the prop value of 'envtype'.

Like I said, ugly, it works, I hope there is a better suggestion.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: I think its same problem [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757318/different-property-variable-for-local-and-prod-environment-spring)

Comment: Take a look at PropertySource and PropertySources enumeration. You can specify the property file path when you run the application using -D flag and use the solution proposed by Tejal. In other words, keep properties files external to build and use command line to point to proper file

Answer (score 0):

you can Autowired  environment in you class  like metioned below and then you can get its property values.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;


String jdbcClassName=environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username");
```