# Automatization Spring Cloud Profile

Tags: java, spring, cloud

Actually have a little problem.

I want switch the url of my bootstrap.yml

It looks as follows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <project-name>
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://<git-repository>:8080
      fail-fast: false
```

This works, but i want have an propertie or anything what can switch if are in local or another enviroment.

I try to see this documentation but dont see any work for me.

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. When do you want to switch the URL? When you package your application?

Comment: When deploy my app in Openshift, in local want local configuration, and when do the pipeline of integration my app, automatically change a dev profile, or pre profile etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Spring Cloud is any different from any Spring application, so you could use the Spring profiles.

Something similar is suggested on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759706/6908551.

You could define a separate `.yml` file just for your cloud config uri, like `cloud-config-dev.yml`, `cloud-config-prod.yml`. Then, for a Java config, you could have something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        String activeProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", "production"); 
        String ymlFilename = "cloud-config-" + activeProfile + ".yml";

        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(ymlFilename));

        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm its a solution but, i try to do when deploy my app in Openshift enviroment, i want dont hardcoding the url or profiles.

Comment: When you start your app in dev env, you would run the app as usually, but you additionally specify the running env, e.g., `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`.

What `System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", "production"); ` does is to set default value to `production`, only if the env variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a bootstrap.yml file by environment.
Define a default bootstrap.yml in `src/main/resources` and define a specific bootstrap.yml file for each environment.

Then there are multiple ways.
Not exhaustive :

1) For each environment where the configuration file differs, run your spring boot jar by specifying the system property `spring.cloud.bootstrap.location` with the expected value such as :
`java -jar ... -Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.location=bootstrap-dev.yml ...`.
That overrides the current location of that file.

2) Take advantage of Spring Boot profile feature : `bootstrap.yml` is compatible with.   For example if the dev profile is enabled, the `bootstrap-dev.properties` in the classpath will be used.

I tend to use the first way because that is more explicit for non Spring Boot users.

Source : [1.3 Changing the Location of Bootstrap Properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-properties)