# Need change envioment of bootstrap in Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring, cloud, spring-cloud

I am new in spring cloud, and i see can change the aplication.yml but i dont know how change bootstrap.yml for local or another enviroment like development, production, or any else.

If can give me any example or similar. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking the same thing i asked days before.

[Here the question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60226910/11532975)

I hope it's what you want